# How to convert iteration into recursion?

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, recursion

I want to know how can I convert a nested for loop into a recursion?

```
public int search(int x, int y, int target)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            int result = Util.findSomthing(i,j); 
            if(result == target)
                return result; 
        }
    }
    return -1; //for target not found
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing this is Java?

Comment: Have you already tried implementing this function recursively? If so, please post your recursion code.

Comment: ``int x, int y, `` what is the purpose of these two param

Comment: It is unclear why you can not do thus homework yourself.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code should not compile because there is no definite `return` statement.

You have not said the purpose of parameter `int x, int y`,

So I'm assuming `x` is the max limit of `i` and `y` is the max limit of `j`

Then one approach would be like that:

```
public int search(int i, int j, int x, int y, int target) {
    if (i == x) return -1; // for target not found
    int result = Util.findSomthing(i, j++); 
    if(result == target) return result;
    return search((j < y ? i : i++) , (j < y ? j : 0), x, y, target);
}
```

And you have to call it as `search(0, 0, 10, 10, 99);`